# LLVM Code generation: fptoui instruction with constant value

Tags: llvm

Let's say we have code

`%conv = fptoui double -1 to i32`

After executing %conv is 4294967295. OK. But when I'm trying to generate such code, and i call

`Builder.CreateFPToUI(val, Builder.getInt32Ty())`

where val is ConstantFP which value is -1, it returns ConstantInt which value is 0 instead of 4294967295! Can somebody explain why?

Upd: 
Example.Let's say I need to generate IR for next code

```
a << -1
```

Code generation will be smth like

```
Value* one; // for 1 literal
Value* minusOne; // for -1
Value* a; //represents variable a
....
one = llvm::ConstantFP::get(Builder.getDoubleTy(), 1);
....
/* Negation. CreateFSub also doesn't emits instruction but returns ConstantFP with -1 value */
minusOne  = CreateFSub(ConstantFP::getZeroValueForNegation(Builder.getDoubleTy()), one);
....
Value* unsignedOne = Builder.CreateFPToUI(minusOne, Builder.getInt32Ty());
....
Value* shift = Builder.CreateShl(a, unsignedOne, "shl");
```

And this all just turns in

```
%shl = shl i32 %a, 0
```

Comment: "returns a constantint with value 0" - what code are you using to get the constant's value?

Comment: I didn't need the value, so i just watched it in debugger. But if you're interested in getting int value you may use smth like dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(value)->getValue().getWord()

Answer (score 0):

From the [language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#id210):

> The ‘fptoui‘ instruction converts its floating point operand into the nearest (rounding towards zero) unsigned integer value. **If the value cannot fit in ty2, the results are undefined**.

-1 does not fit in any unsigned integral type... so you get undefined results.

And if you wonder how come you get two different things from the same IR, than you should be aware it's not the same IR: the result of the `IRBuilder::CreateFPToUI` call is, as you have observed, a value (`ConstantInt`) and not an instruction, since it was constant-folded.

Comment: As far as I now, -1 fits i32 ty(it doesn't distinguish signed/unsigned) and so IR code i gave above always returns 4294967295, which is correct. The question is why the result of value returned by CreateFPToUI differs from the result of instruction it emits?